# How to write "or" inside dependencies in makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

How to write "or" inside dependencies in makefile, I need to check both .c and .cpp:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)

myTarget: $(SOURCES:.cpp||.c=.o)
         g++ ...
```

It is not working, could you use an "or" in this situation?

Comment: Don't think his is such a good idea. Compiling C and C++ with the same compiler and options doesn't always turn out well. I'd handle this with two separate rules.

Comment: You *cannot* compile C code with C++ compiler.

Comment: Power can, but I will not, I was just curious even on the question of using "or", as for c code, nor compile it as a .o file, when I need it, I compile as a library that gets easier.

Comment: @PerduGames what do you mean, "*Power can*"? In the general case, C code cannot be compiled with a C++ compiler. Some C code happens to be valid C++ as well, but relying on that really isn't a good idea, and it's quite easy to write perfectly valid C that *isn't* valid C++ (e.g. use an identifier that's a *reserved keyword* in C++ or use designated struct initializers and so on)

Comment: Is correct, I meant that depending on the code will compile yes, but yes, if it is a less generic code will accuse errors. And no, I will not compile c with the c ++ compiler, it was just a question of "or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using GNU make. If you are, you can use two calls of the function `subst`.

```
INTERMEDIATE=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS=$(subst .c,.o,$(INTERMEDIATE))

myTarget:$(OBJECTS)
```

If you don't want to use `INTERMEDIATE`, you can use:

```
OBJECTS=$(subst .c,.o,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the file name only, without the directories?
here is:

MyTarget: $ (SOURCES: .cpp = .o)

I get "scr / file.o", but I just wanted " file.o" to use it when creating .o files in an "obj " folder instead of "src", could I do something like that?

Comment: @PerduGames,you can use the `notdir` function to strip out `src` from `$(SOURCES)` and then use the function `addprefix` to add `obj/` to each .o file. You can read more about the file manipulation functions from [its documentation site](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions).

Comment: I'll leave it here:

`SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
#Retrieve prefix and suffix
OBJCLEAN=$(notdir $(basename $(SOURCES)))
#Add new prefix and suffix
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(OBJCLEAN)))`